# Is it possible to use a prepositional phrase with a gerundive/gerund?

Tags: idiom, preposition, gerund, gerundive

can we use prepositional phrases (like "de domo") linked to a gerund or 
 a gerundive, can it act as an object?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Gerunds and gerundive constructions can act as objects to a praeposition. But I'm not entirely sure what kind of sentence you have in mind. Could give a partial example?